# Connect Laptop to External Monitor

Tags: display, configuration, hdmi, external-monitor, vga

Recently I've got a monitor Dell I want to connect to my lapto Dell as well. Here are some pics of the elements.

[Pic 1: DP port laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3G70.jpg)

[Pic 2: Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyeD3.jpg)

[Pic 3: Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZQ9m.jpg)

The Dell laptop has the DP and HDMI ports (NO VGA ports). The DP port is connected to the box (see Pic 1). The monitor has a VGA port connected as well to the box (see Pic 2). I would like to pass the desktop of my laptop to the monitor, but when I try configure the monitor, it puts NO CABLE...POWER SAVE MODE in any of the VGA, DP or HDMI settings (see Pic 3). Should I need another cable or it is just a problem of configuration with my laptop as well?

Comment: It would be better if you add the box's model to the question.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov the model is DW15

Comment: it is not enough cause name is too short and the brand/vendor name is missed. Provide full name or a link to the site and the device, please

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov here it is http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-business-dock-wd15-with-180w-adapter/apd/450-aeuo/pc-accessories

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the USB cable shall be connected as well according to the [documentation](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_docking_stations/dell-dock-wd15_user%27s_guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: the USB cable connected to what?

Comment: connected to PC and to the box

Comment: but why should I need to connect a USB cable from the laptop to the box to see the image in the monitor?

Comment: Did you try? Did it work? I just interpret what I am seeing in the instruction